# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: .net, farpoint-spread

I upgraded an asp.net website from 2.0 to 4.0 framework. This websites uses **farpoint**.
After framework upgrade, one of the page is throwing the error mentioned in the title.
**FarPoint.Web.Spread** assembly registred in this page and **FPSPREAD** is used. 
**FarPoint.Web.Spread.dll** assembly version is **3.0.2003.2005**. Do i need to refer any latest dll of the same or is there any other fix for this issue?
I am very new to farpoint, Please help me....

Many Thanks,
Sreekanth Mohan

Comment: Set `EnablePartialRendering` property of ScriptManager to `false` and check where exception comes from

Comment: EnablePartialRendering= false is not working. Thank you for your comment... :)

Comment: I understand that this won't fix a problem but which error message you get with disabled partial rendering?

Comment: "Input string was not in a correct format" is getting with disabled partial rendering...!! now only i am getting this on FPSPREAD paging. Thanks  @YuriyRozhovetskiy

Comment: From the error message, it seems this is some type casting issue. But don't know from where it is throwing...!! Please help me... :(

Comment: unfortunatelly I lost my crystal ball so show your code

Answer (score 3):

Spread 3 probably isn't compatible with 4.0 Framework.  Have you tried upgrading Spread?  You can download a free trial of Spread.NET 6 [here](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/SpreadNET/)

And [click here](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/SpreadNetReadme/upgrade.html) to view the notes on how to upgrade spread controls in your project from 3 to 6

Comment: Yes, i upgraded it to Spread 6.0 and it is working fine now. Thank you so much @daved